# How Android ViewModel insures that, it has to bind with the same Activity or Fragment(in case of Screen Rotation)?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am working on Android ViewModel right now. One Question keep arising in my mind. How ViewModel insures to rebind with the same Activity or Fragment, after screen rotation, despite of we are creating a new object in onCreate or onCreateView?

Is anyone have proper answer for this, please let me know. I had tried to find out solution at so many tutorials.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new instance of `ViewModelProvider` is created, the first parameter is `activity.getViewModelStore()` and according to documentation,

> Returns the {@link ViewModelStore} associated with this activity
>
> Overriding this method is no longer supported and this method will be made
>   `final` in a future version of ComponentActivity.
>   @return a {@code ViewModelStore}
>   @throws IllegalStateException if called before the Activity is attached to the Application
>   instance i.e., before onCreate()

it returns a `ViewModelStore` object. So what is a `ViewModelStore` ?

```
/**
 * Class to store {@code ViewModels}.
 * <p>
 * An instance of {@code ViewModelStore} must be retained through configuration changes:
 * if an owner of this {@code ViewModelStore} is destroyed and recreated due to configuration
 * changes, new instance of an owner should still have the same old instance of
 * {@code ViewModelStore}.
 * <p>
 * If an owner of this {@code ViewModelStore} is destroyed and is not going to be recreated,
 * then it should call {@link #clear()} on this {@code ViewModelStore}, so {@code ViewModels} would
 * be notified that they are no longer used.
 * <p>
 * Use {@link ViewModelStoreOwner#getViewModelStore()} to retrieve a {@code ViewModelStore} for
 * activities and fragments.
 */
 public class ViewModelStore {

 private final HashMap<String, ViewModel> mMap = new HashMap<>();

 final void put(String key, ViewModel viewModel) {
    ViewModel oldViewModel = mMap.put(key, viewModel);
    if (oldViewModel != null) {
        oldViewModel.onCleared();
    }
 }

 final ViewModel get(String key) {
    return mMap.get(key);
 }

 Set<String> keys() {
    return new HashSet<>(mMap.keySet());
 }

 /**
  *  Clears internal storage and notifies ViewModels that they are no longer used.
  */
 public final void clear() {
    for (ViewModel vm : mMap.values()) {
        vm.clear();
    }
    mMap.clear();
  }
}
```

Basically, it’s a class which has a `HashMap` whose key is `DEFAULT_KEY + “:” + canonicalName` where `DEFAULT_KEY` is `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.DefaultKey` and value is the `ViewModel`

That means every activity and fragment has a `ViewModelStore` which keeps all the declared `ViewModels` in the activity or fragment respectively.

But How `ViewModelStore` survives orientation change?

In the documentation of `ViewModelStore` it’s defined that

> if an owner of this {@code ViewModelStore} is destroyed and recreated due to configuration
>   * changes, new instance of an owner should still have the same old instance of
>   * {@code ViewModelStore}.

So it’s activities responsibility to retain the `ViewModelStore` during orientation change.

If we go back to `activity.getViewModelStore()` implementation, then we’ll find the answer.

```
if (mViewModelStore == null) {
    NonConfigurationInstances nc =
        (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (nc != null) {
        // Restore the ViewModelStore from NonConfigurationInstances
        mViewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
    }
    if (mViewModelStore == null) {
        mViewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
    }
}
```

The activity does so by using something called `NonConfigurationInstances`. `NonConfigurationInstances` is a static final class

```
static final class NonConfigurationInstances {
    Object custom;
    ViewModelStore viewModelStore;
}
```

So it first checks whether there is already an `viewmodelstore` stored in `NonConfigurationInstances` if not it creates a new `ViewModelStore` or returns the existing `ViewModelStore`.

Then why doesn’t `ViewModel` survive low memory or `finish()` scenarios?

`ViewModelStore` has a `clear()` method :

```
/**
  *  Clears internal storage and notifies ViewModels that they are no longer used.
  */
public final void clear() {
    for (ViewModel vm : mMap.values()) {
        vm.onCleared();
    }
    mMap.clear();
}
```

So this `clear()` method gets called in `onDestroy()` of activity or fragment which clears the `HashMap` except during configuration changes. Here is the code :

```
if (mViewModelStore != null && !isChangingConfigurations) {
    mViewModelStore.clear();
}
```

Now you know the secret recipe of how ViewModel survives configuration change.

Happy coding…

**IMPORTANT** : *I don not believe in taking credits of someone else's work. To make it easily available on stack **overflow** I have copy-pasted everything from article [The curious case of Android ViewModel](https://proandroiddev.com/the-curious-case-of-survival-of-viewmodel-afe074992fbc)*

Comment: This is somewhat great @buzzingsilently, although this article has some flaws, but I got my answer, and as of now I am accepting your answer!